# FB.getLoginStatus doesn't work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The FB.getLoginStatus function doesn't work for me for some reason - although it used to for some time.
Very basic code below, and the alert never popups - looks like FB.getLoginStatus never calls the supplied function.
Any ideas ?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({ appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert("Hi there");
    });
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

If your app is in Sandbox Mode see this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240058389381072

Also read the comments by Philip Bulley

> [...] Essentially sandboxed applications are invisible to non-app-developers. If there is no user currently logged into Facebook, Facebook will act as if your sandboxed application doesn't exist at all (FB obviously doesn't know you're an app developer, and thus the app is invisible!).

This bug has been confirmed and assigned.

Comment: Oh God, thank you for explaining this. I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure out what the problem was. Switched off Sandbox Mode and now FB.getLoginStatus works fine. (Which calls into question the value of Sandbox Mode... but oh well) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In which platform you are developing the application??If it is FBML then check [FBJS-Facebook JavaScript](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/).I think alert will not work in FBML application.
I got this working..Just check

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false});
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

         /* All the events registered */
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
             // do something with response
             login();
         });
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
             // do something with response
             logout();
         });

         FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
             if (response.session) {
                 // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                 login();
             }
         });
     };
```