# Unable to get login status from facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am new to facebook app development. I am trying to get access token from the facebook. For that, I am trying to check my login status using the following code

```
<html>
<body>
 <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'appId', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    alert('page 1');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert('Page 2');
        // connected
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
      }
     });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i executes the above code, it shows a login button where i can login sucessfully. I can get 'Page 1' alert but I cannot get 'Page 2' alert. I dont know what's wrong with this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have enabled <kbd>Sanbox mode</kbd> in your application. If yes, and if you're not currently logged in as a user that has admin or developer role for this application, this will happen. Try if it'll work after disabling Sandbox for a while. Check answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8485361/1816426

Of course I'm assuming, that `appId: 'appId'` part is an example only and you have correct application ID in your code taken from application's settings.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips to get you going:

1) Check if your appID is valid (I'm hoping you didn't literally write `appId`, and have actually inserted an appID which you registered)

`FB.init({appId: 'appId', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});`

2) try looking at the actual response by doing:

`alert(response);`

*The details of the response are stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

But my guess is that your application isn't registered correctly, or that you haven't inserted a correct appID in your `appID` field. That is usually the case.